# How to set id in handlebar template dynamically?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

With a Handlebars.js template like this..

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class="span4">
    {{#each book in books}}
        {{ view Ember.TextField valueBinding='book.name' placeholder="Book Name" }}
    {{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

And Data Like this :

```
books: [{"id": 1, "name": "ABC"}, {"id": 2, "name": "XYZ"}],
```

Now What is the best way to attach individual id with each text field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the lastest version I can do this using `{{view Ember.TextField id=book.id ...}}`, maybe in your case will be `{{view Ember.TextField idBinding='book.id' ...}}`. So just put the `id` atribute with the corresponding binding and will work.

This is a fiddle with this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/97rD2/, you will see in the console output the id of each rendered `Ember.TextField`